# Limiting Resources in Production Website with Flask and Web Scraping & Submission with Selenium

Tags: selenium, flask, queue, resources, production

I have created a website in Flask that gives the user the ability to run a script that will crawl through websites in order to scrape/submit data for them. Running this script does take significant resources on my own computer. It is multi-threaded. My two concerns are. The scripts are not something that the use needs to execute frequently. One, I would likely use every few months--i've limited it's use to weekly. The other, could be used several times a week. I fear that the script requests will overlap and crash the system.

1. Though the multi-threaded aspect of Selenium has proven to work very
   well, will this be true when the script gets executed concurrently?
2. What is the best way of dealing with the potential high resource
   demand?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, this is how I solved the issue. I wanted to limit the cpu-heavy processes to one at a time. So i created a global queue, added to it I would have otherwise initiated the cpu-heavy call, and created a ongoing threaded function which processes the queue.

## Initialize Queue

```
  def init():
    global crawl_queue
    crawl_queue = Queue()
```

## Process Queue

```
    def process_crawling_queue():
    from flaskblog.books.routes import populate_from_amazon, send_async_mail, submit_books_to_websites
    from flask_mail import Message
    from flask import flash, url_for

    while True:
        size = settings.crawl_queue.qsize()
        # print(f'Processes in queue: {size}')
        if size:
            p_name, *args = settings.crawl_queue.get()
            if p_name == 'Populate_From_Amazon':
                with app.app_context():
                    count = populate_from_amazon(*args, app=app)
                    user = args[0]
                    msg = Message(f'Finished Populating Books',
                                  sender=app.config['MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER'],
                                  recipients=[user.email])
                    msg.html = f'{count} book(s) have been added/updated. <a href = {url_for("books.edit_books", _external=True)}> Edit them here</a> and then you can promote them.'
                    send_async_mail(app, msg)
            elif p_name == "Submit_Books_To_Websites":
                with app.app_context():
                    total_submissions = submit_books_to_websites(*args, app=app)
                    email = args[1]['email']
                    msg = Message(f'Finished Submitting Your Books',
                                  sender=app.config['MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER'],
                                  recipients=[email])
                    msg.html = f'We have submitted your {len(args[0])} book(s) a total of {total_submissions} times. Good luck on the promotion! '
                    send_async_mail(app, msg)
            else:
                print(f'function {p_name} not recognized.')
        time.sleep(3)
```

## Add to Queue

```
  data = ('Populate_From_Amazon', user)
  crawl_queue.put(data)
```